# AcceptAllChanges causes Entity Framework to ... not accept the changes?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm using .NET 3.5 SP1. I have a simple script that deletes some entities.

```
var people = (from Person p in context.People
              where p.FirstName == "Testy" && 
                    p.LastName == "McTesterson"
              select p).ToList();
people.ForEach(p => context.DeleteObject(p));

//context.AcceptAllChanges();
context.SaveChanges();
```

If I uncomment `AcceptAllChanges()`, the objects are not deleted. If I keep it commented, the entities are deleted. Why does EF behave like this? It seems counter productive.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That is the behavior of `AcceptAllChanges`. Accepting changes "resets" the internal state of `ObjectContext`. It means that all entities which were added or modified are set to *"unchanged"* state and all entities which were deleted are detached from the context.

In contrast, `SaveChanges` method iterates the internal state of `ObjectContext` and creates INSERT db commands for each entity with a state of *added*, UPDATE db command for each entity in *modified* state and DELETE db command for each entity in *deleted* state. `SaveChanges` by default accepts all changes after it executes all commands.

If you run `AcceptAllChanges` before `SaveChanges` you clear all changes and there is nothing to execute in DB. The reason why this method exists is that you can turn off default `SaveChanges` behavior; in such a case, you must accept changes manually after you execute `SaveChanges`. Otherwise the next call to `SaveChanges` will execute the changes again.

Comment: Much clear than other pages I read trying to explain this and much more accurate than other posts suggesting that this was a fix to the unstated problem I was having. Thanks!